# An axiom for John Major's Equality

Tags: dependent-type, coq, proof-theory, calculus-of-constructions, agda

In the the standard library of Coq, there is the axiom:

```
Axiom JMeq_eq : forall (A:Type) (x y:A), JMeq x y -> x = y.
```

Why isn't it provable? Can it be reduced to more elementary axioms? Is it consistent with impredicative Set? Is there the same axiom in Agda?

Comment: The axiom can be proved with Streicher's K. See e.g. [axioms.v](https://github.com/imdea-software/fcsl-pcm/blob/master/pcm/axioms.v) 
file from fcsl-pcm library by Aleks Nanevski. There is no direct proof of the axiom in the form you stated, but it can be done with the help of `dynE` lemma at the end of the linked file.

Comment: @AntonTrunov What is the idea of the proof starting from Streicher's K?

Comment: We know that Streicher's K is equivalent to Invariance by Substitution of Reflexive Equality Proofs (see [EqDepFacts.v](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts.html)) an this last one implies the injectivity of the projection of the dependent pair (called `inj_pair2` in Coq). From `JMeq_eq x y` follows `existT id A x = existT id A y` and using `inj_pair2` we get `x = y`.

Comment: There is also a homotopy type theory explanation: https://homotopytypetheory.org/2012/11/21/on-heterogeneous-equality/

Comment: In Agda (or by using Equations), you can prove it using dependent pattern matching, which is itself equivalent to Streicher's K (there is a limited form of DPM available even without assuming K, but not enough to prove JMEq_Eq).

Comment: Here's a [discussion](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/316071/) on the invalidity of K